# "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linkedserver" returned message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions."

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, linked-server

I have a database in a SQL Server 2014 AG group (AG1).- two nodes.

On both nodes, a linked server is set up.  I am selecting data from a table from AG group (AG1) database and inserting into a linked server (a database from another AG group(AG2)).  The only statement in the transaction is an insert statement.  It is not a distributed transaction.

Why do i get the following error?

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LinkedserverListener" returned message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.".
>   Msg 7391, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "LinkedServerListener" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

Sample code is a below.

```
Drop table #Myatran
Select 'ABC' name into #Myatran

DECLARE @pndstop_ps NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @pndstop_ps = 
N'
INSERT INTO '+ 'linkedserver'+'.DB.dbo.MyaTEST(Name) SELECT name FROM #Myatran
'
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRANSACTION

EXEC sp_executeSQl @pndstop_ps

SET XACT_ABORT OFF
```

Answer (score 6):

SQL Server 2014 Availability Groups [does not support](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36140.sql-server-2016-high-availability-enhancements-alwayson-availability-group.aspx) distributed transactions.

SQL Server 2016 has limited support for [distributed transactions, however, SQL Server 2017 has the best support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-availability-group-for-distributed-transactions).

Consider using SQL Server Integration Services or bcp in/out, or some other tool for Extract-Transform-Load, or ETL, operations.

FYI, you may not be aware of this, but doing an `INSERT INTO ...` into a table on a linked server results in the local SQL Server performing a series of cursor calls for *each row* inserted into the target table.

To prove this, I've created a linked server and ran the following code to setup a simple test-bed.

First, we'll create a table in tempdb at the linked server:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
SET @cmd = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''dbo.InsertTest'', N''U'') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.InsertTest;
CREATE TABLE dbo.InsertTest
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);';

EXEC [LinkedServer].tempdb.sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Here, I'm creating a local table in tempdb to hold some rows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.InsertTest', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.InsertTest;CREATE TABLE dbo.InsertTest
(
    id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT INTO dbo.InsertTest (id)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.object_id, c.column_id)
FROM sys.columns c;
```

a quick check to see if we have rows in the source table:

```
SELECT CountOfRows = COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.InsertTest;
```

```
╔═════════════╗
║ CountOfRows ║
╠═════════════╣
║         990 ║
╚═════════════╝
```

Here, we'll insert rows from the local source table into the remote linked-server table.  I've setup a trace running on the target server so we can see the T-SQL statements issued against it.

```
INSERT INTO [LinkedServer].tempdb.dbo.InsertTest (ID)
SELECT it.ID
FROM dbo.InsertTest it;
```

The output:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                                             SET XACT_ABORT OFF                                              ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ declare @p1 int                                                                                             ║
║ set @p1=NULL                                                                                                ║
║ declare @p2 bigint                                                                                          ║
║ set @p2=NULL                                                                                                ║
║ exec [sys].sp_getschemalock @p1 output,@p2 output,N'"tempdb"."dbo"."InsertTest"'                            ║
║ select @p1, @p2                                                                                             ║
║ declare @p1 int                                                                                             ║
║ set @p1=NULL                                                                                                ║
║ declare @p3 int                                                                                             ║
║ set @p3=229378                                                                                              ║
║ declare @p4 int                                                                                             ║
║ set @p4=294916                                                                                              ║
║ declare @p5 int                                                                                             ║
║ set @p5=NULL                                                                                                ║
║ exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output,N'select * from "tempdb"."dbo"."InsertTest"',@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output ║
║ select @p1, @p3, @p4, @p5                                                                                   ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=1                                           ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=2                                           ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=3                                           ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=4                                           ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=5                                           
.
.
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=987                                         ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=988                                         ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=989                                         ║
║ exec sp_cursor 180150027,4,0,N'[tempdb].[dbo].[InsertTest]',@id=990                                         ║
║ exec [sys].sp_releaseschemalock 1                                                                           ║
║ exec sp_cursorclose 180150027                                                                               ║
║ exec sp_reset_connection                                                                                    ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

However, if you run the insert from the target server, like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.InsertTest (ID)
SELECT it.ID
FROM [LinkedServer].tempdb.dbo.InsertTest it;
```

You see this in the trace:

```
╔════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║        TextData        ║                                                ║
╠════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ SET STATISTICS XML ON  ║                                                ║
║                        ║ INSERT INTO dbo.InsertTest (ID)                ║
║                        ║ SELECT it.ID                                   ║
║                        ║ FROM [CP708-D377\MV].tempdb.dbo.InsertTest it; ║
║ SET STATISTICS XML OFF ║                                                ║
╚════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Clearly, it pays to run the insert at the target server, instead of the source server.